# SaveChanges está truncando o valor decimal

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Vou refazer a pergunta:
Preciso gravar no banco de dados com quatro casas decimais. Por exemplo. Na view eu digito um valor percentual de 56,78%. No banco deverá ser gravado 0.5678. Por isso o campo é decima 18,4, esse é padrão para campos decimal aqui na empresa. Na aplicação e no banco, os campos são dessa forma(18,4). Acontece que quando eu gravo um valor decimal, como no exemplo acima, ele está truncando a parte decimal, gravando apenas 0.5600 e não 0.5678. Já percorri o sistema para tentar descobrir em que ponto está sendo truncado e até o `savechanges()` eu tenho 0.5678. Após isso, quando sou redirecionado para a Index, aí aparece 56,00 e não 56,78. Ao executar o `SaveChages()` rodo o select direto no banco e tenho lá 0.5600. Como resolver isso

No output do debug eu pego isso no `SaveChanges()`

```
INSERT [dbo].[AzureDiscountGroup]([Id], [Descricao], [PercDesconto])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2)

-- @0: '19' (Type = Int32)

-- @1: 'FFF' (Type = String, Size = 50)

-- @2: '0,3497' (Type = Decimal, Precision = 18, Scale = 2)
```

Veja que o scale é 2 e não 4. Como altero isso?

Comment: o desconto é divido por 100 na seguinte linha `model.PercDesconto = model.PercDesconto / 100;`

Comment: Como o colega comentou... porque você está dividindo o valor por 100?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, retornando hoje após 3 dias em casa. É dividido por 100, para gravar no banco 35,56% no banco ficaria 0.3556. E para mostrar na tela deveria pegar do banco multiplicar por 100 para ficar 35,56

Comment: Então qual é a dúvida e por que o campo é `decimal(18,4)` no banco? Nada dessa pergunta faz sentido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## O que está acontecendo?

O Entity Framework por padrão trata `decimal` com `precision` 2.

## Como resolver

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
   protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Entity<Class>().Property(object => object.property).HasPrecision(12, 4);

       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   }
}
```

Mais informações podem ser encontradas aqui:

[EF decimal scale and precision convention](https://storiknow.com/entity-framework-decimal-scale-and-precision-convention/)

[Decimal precision EF codefirst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504660/decimal-precision-and-scale-in-ef-code-first)

Comment: Já fiz no mapping, exatamente como o Ronaldo respondeu. Como não respondi antes, vou marcar a do Ronaldo como correta.